# ping6 localip failed when ping6 -s 15992 localip in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ping

```
uname -a
Linux ligang-virtual-machine 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ifconfig ens33 |grep inet6
        inet6 fe80::3c3f:a926:e237:30df  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 1510::6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>

ping6 local ip 1510::6 with -s define packet size 15991-----success
ping6 -s 15991 1510::6
PING 1510::6(1510::6) 15991 data bytes
15999 bytes from 1510::6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
15999 bytes from 1510::6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

ping6 local ip 1510::6 with -s define packet size 15992-----failed
ping6 -s 15992 1510::6
PING 1510::6(1510::6) 15992 data bytes
^C
--- 1510::6 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4092ms
```

I see the pcap with Wireshark, the icmpv6 csum is incorrect when the payload is 16000.

[image]

Has the bug been modified?

Comment: version is Ubuntu 22.04 amd64

Comment: uname -v
#36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2

Comment: I think this problem happens every version， but centos doesn't have this bug。

Comment: it is easy to try.       setip：ip -6 addr add 1510::6/64 dev ens33；  ping：ping6 -s 15992 1510::6